# How to put plain text into navbar in bootstrap4

Tags: bootstrap-4

In `bootstrap3`, there is this `.navbar-text` to use, so I can put some plain text into navbar. Something like "Signed in as xxx".

But in `bootstrap4`, I can't find the class to put plain text into `.navbar`. There is only `.navlink`.

This [document](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/navbar/) seems not revearling enough information.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a not link , cuold be print like plain text.
Look:

http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/navbar/#brand

here is using a header, nd is a plaint text.
So if you try to use p, or span, ... this could be drawn as plain text as ypu like.
Try and tell us.
Thanks

Comment: Thanks. but not as good as the old one in bs3. Brand font-size is too big. I couldn't find a helper to change font-size..

Comment: hi, change the h1 to p, and tell us if it that you need

Comment: Tried that. the brand class has set the font-size pretty high.

Comment: and, if you try to change the class http://getbootstrap.com/css/#type???

Comment: Hi, add small tag between the navbar-brand gives me a fair font-size that I can accept. :) but it's still not align horizontally perfect with the item. If this is the best it could do, I can accept. Thanks again.

Comment: sure can be done better, have you update the fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

You can try 2 methods, kindly refer below code:

1) Using `.navbar-brand`:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-light" style="background-color: #e3f2fd;">
  <!-- Navbar content -->
  <span class="navbar-brand">Signed in as xxx</span>
</nav>
```

2) Using `nav-item`:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-light" style="background-color: #e3f2fd;">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">Signed in as xxx
      </li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

Demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/o6vm0mLj/)

Comment: Not quite when there is other nav-item in the ul. https://jsfiddle.net/o6vm0mLj/2/  please see demo

Comment: what you exactly want  ?